# by the hour / per hour - do they mean the same?

Tags: meaning

**He charges 20 pounds per hour.**

Would this mean the same?

**He charges 20 pounds by the hour.**

Comment: "20 pounds by the hour" does sound strange, but if someone were to say this, I would take it to mean that an hour is the smallest billable time unit: 1.5 hours would be billed as 2 hours (i.e. 40 pounds rather than 30 pounds).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Only the first one is correct.

You might say "He charges by the hour" (meaning he isn't paid a fixed amount for the job, but charges more for longer)  But if you are describing the rate, use "per".

Comment: "He charges by the hour" - is OK. But this is not OK? "He charges 20 pounds by the hour" It's strange.

Comment: @user1425  I agree with James.  "He charges 20 pounds by the hour" doesn't sound natural.  I think it's because *by the hour* describes a **method** of charging, and adding "20 pounds" mixes amount and method.

Comment: Question: "A. Would this mean the same? B." Answer: "No, only the first one. You might say B, but under some conditions, use A." What? After reading your answer several times I still don't know whether you think they're both correct or only one of them is correct (and which one).

Comment: I agree with Stef. I nearly added an answer that was essentially a duplicate to this answer because I didn't understand it at first. You're not wrong, it's just confusing as written.

Comment: @Stef note the difference between B, "he charges **20 pounds** by the hour," and the expression in the answer, "he charges by the hour." The second is commonly used to describe the method of payment calculation; the first is an unusual combination of the second and A.

Comment: Depending on the setting, you might also here someone say ‘He charges 20 pounds pro-rated by the hour.’, though that would mean that half an hour would cost 10 pounds (which may or may not be the case if you just say ‘He charges 20 pounds per hour.’).

Comment: @Stef Read it as "No. Only the first one *is correct*."

Answer (score 5):

To add to James K's answer, Americans generally say "he charges 20 dollars *an* hour," although we also use *per*.

Answer (score 0):

*[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/by-the-hour#:%7E:text=by%20the%20hour%E2%80%8B%2F%E2%80%8B,always)*, *[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+the+hour)* and *[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hour)* say

> ## by the hour
>
> **1. based on an hour of work**
> *Are you paid by the hour?*
>
> **2.** by the hour​/​from hour to hour **continuously, or all the time**
> *The fire grew bigger by the hour.*

TFD

> 1. **Per hour**; at an hourly rate.
>    *Of course he's drawing out this project—he gets paid by the hour!*
> 2. Continuously;
>    *My confidence in his ability to lead us through this crisis is decreasing by the hour.*
>    *Sir, the situation is worsening by the hour—how should we proceed?*

CD

> ### hour
>
> a period of 60 minutes:
> He gets paid **by the hour** (= gets a particular amount of money for each hour he works).

> **You'll be paid by the hour for this job**.

This means the employee receives an hourly wage.